# Условие на значение атрибута WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли возможность задать условие когда определенный атрибут данного товара равен чему-то, то вывести изображение, например.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<?php 

$sezon = $product->get_attribute('pa_tire-season');
 echo '<span class="sold-out">' . $sezon . '</span>';
if ($sezon == "winter"){
        echo "Hello World!";
    }
   ?>
```